# ARM Template: Firewall rule is not being created for database server

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm deploying an Azure database server with a ARM template which includes a firewall rule to allow all IP addresses. The deployment finishes without errors, however, the firewall rule doesn't seem to be created when I check the Portal.

```
  "resources": {
        "name": "mydbserver",
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
        "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "mydbserver"
        },
        "properties": {
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('dbserverUsername')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('dbserverPassword')]"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "type": "firewallRules",
                "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', 'mydbserver')]"
                ],
                "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                "properties": {
                    "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                    "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Azure portal
[image]

Comment: Why do you have two `resources` blocks? The second block seems incorrect

Comment: The nested format was suggested by the autocomplete in VSCode ARM plugin

Comment: I don't see `resources` block here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers#tabpanel_1_json

Answer (score 0):

Adding this rule (AllowAllWindowsAzureIps) manually in the portal resulted in an error stating "This rule name is already in use for 'Allow Azure services and resources to access this server' setting.".

So, it is clear that the rule name is reserved for the below outlined setting. Everything was working as intended after all.

[image]